# How can i split a string into two on the first occurrence of a character

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a code to list all the components in my Linux server. The list is stored in a file. I will ready line by line and have to split the components from version and store in 2 different strings.

For eg: one of my line shows console-3.45.1-0 where console is the component and 3.45.1-0 is the version. If I use split,

```
print components[i].split('-')
```

I can see `['console', '3.45.1', '0\r\r']` which is not what I wanted. How can I split into 2 strings on the first occurrence of '-' ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) takes a maxsplit argument, pass 1 to only split on the first `-`:

```
print components[i].rstrip().split('-',1)
```

To store the output in two variables:

```
In [7]: s = "console-3.45.1-0"

In [8]: a,b = s.split("-",1)

In [9]: a
Out[9]: 'console'

In [10]: b
Out[10]: '3.45.1-0'
```

Comment: Yeah. That worked. But how can i store into 2 different strings?

Comment: @Roshanr, if you want to keep the `'\r\r'` remove the rstrip call

Comment: @Roshanr, added how to store the output

Comment: @Padriac. Excellent and a fast solution. Many thanks. I will accept this as the answer

Comment: No prob, you're welcome.